# No connectivity between azure VMs

Tags: networking, virtualization, azure

In my azure environment, I have 4 VMsx running Windows Server 2012 R2

- 10.0.0.4 (AD, DNS)
- 10.0.0.5 (ADFS)
- 10.0.0.6 (MSSQLSERVER)
- 10.0.0.7 (IIS)

All of the machines are connected by an azure virtual network, and the network's dns server address is set to **10.0.0.4**

I've noticed that, although the machines register correctly in the dns and the name resolution appears to work, none of the machines can connect to each other either via ICMP nor TCP

For instance, a ping attempt from **10.0.0.6** to **10.0.0.5** results in :

*C:>ping devua-adfs01.devua.sys

Pinging devua-adfs01.devua.sys [10.0.0.5] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.0.0.5:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),*

Can anyone advise me on how to diagnose and fix the connectivity? I've been banging my head against the desk for the past 8 hrs. This looks awfully close to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/646822/new-azure-vms-on-virtual-network-have-no-connectivity-to-anything) question but no solution has been offered.

Comment: Does windows firewall happen to be on? Have you defined particular network rulesets for connectivity between VMs in your azure subnet?

Comment: firewalls are on, but disabling them yields no results. I havent defined any rulesets, at least not knowingly

Comment: I'm a little rusty on Azure, but maybe this: in Azure dashboard, open the dashboard for a VM, go to endpoints section, add an endpoint for port you need.  You may also need to configure the ACL.

Comment: endpoints are for external communication, I'm talking about communication using the internal private network. I'm looking to avoid traffic going outside of my cloud service.

Comment: This is weird, VNets are made so the VMs can talk to each other freely, I actually have the same setup and its working fine. I would highly recommend contacting the Azure support for this one as it seems to be an internal issue.